# Why does Jenkins always access the AD server mail group during the build job?

Tags: jenkins, ldap

I use Jenkins ldaps configured by my OA account, and all functions are well. But my MIS colleague told me that during my colleague build the job, my OA account always accessed the LDAPs server mail group.
Can someone give me some advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess, that Jenkins is trying get infos for the user triggering the build. Commonly this is used to send a mail to the user, who broke the build.

You can turn off this behavior under Jenkins -> Configure Jenkins -> Global Security -> LDAP -> "Disable Ldap Email Resolver". *You can also try to enable the cache on the same page, which will reduce the queries made to your Active Directory/LDAP.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! 
My MIS colleague told me that the number of visits is huge, hundreds of thousands of times. So can this behavior be cancelled?

Comment: Under Jenkins -> Configure Jenkins -> Global Security -> LDAP -> "Disable Ldap Email Resolver". You can also try to enable the cache on the same page. Let me know if it works and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Hi crash.  Until today, MIS colleagues have not reported other problems, I think this solution is OK

Comment: @Bob_X_Liu Added this to my answer.

Comment: Too bad, this doesn't work using the "Active Directory" security realm.
Does anyone have a guide how to properly migrate from the "Active Directory" plugin to the "LDAP" plugin? The LDAP Plugin has a lot of settings that I don't understand.